# why t-sql patindex not work with declared variable?

Tags: t-sql

why this query is not work correctly?

```
declare @s nvarchar
set @s = 'abcd'
select patindex('%b%', @s)
```

it is return zero.

Comment: i accept every usefull question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It works if you add a size to your initial declaration of the varchar:

```
declare @s nvarchar(10) 
set @s = 'abcd' 
select patindex('%b%', @s)
```

Comment: +1 - beat me to it! Will keep my answer anyway for it's pointer to reference on similar related gotchas

Answer (score 2):

It's because if you don't define the size of the NVARCHAR variable, it will be defaulting to size 1. So @s will only ever contain 'a'.

You need to always be careful, to make sure you define the sizes explicitly as different scenarios behave differently as [I blogged here](http://www.adathedev.co.uk/2010/04/sql-cast-to-varchar-without-size.html).

So, just change

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR
```

to (e.g.)

```
DECLARE @s NVARCHAR(20)
```